# multidimensional std::intializer_list where the number of dimensions is specified as a template argument of its class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have a multidimensional array which currently does not accept initializer_list initialization, but I want to allow that. However, it seems I can't specify an arbitrary number of nesting for std::initializer_list based on a template argument.

```
// e.g. 5D array:
array<int, 5> arr(10, 5, 20, 34, 10); // the integers are the lengths of each dimension.

// This is what I'm trying to achieve on top of the above:
// creates the array and initializes it
array<int, 5> arr{ {{{{0, 1}}}}, {{{{1, 1}}}} };

// class signature:
// template <template T, unsigned dimensions> array { ... }
// --> where T is the array element type
```

The answer does not necessarily have to use `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Well, `array<T, 1>` should accept an `initializer_list<T>`, and `array<T, N>` should accept an `initializer_list<array<T, N-1>>`...

Comment: Do you really mean 5d array, or just a 2d array with uneven columns (jagged array)?

Comment: @JesseGood: True multidimensional array.

Comment: @ZachSaw: So, to access an element, you would do something like this `array[1][1][1][1][1];`?

Comment: @JesseGood: arr(1,1,1,1,1).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
template<typename BASE, int N>
struct nested {
  typedef std::initializer_list<typename nested<BASE,N-1>::initializer_list> initializer_list;
};

template<typename BASE>
struct nested<BASE,0> {
  typedef BASE initializer_list;
};


template<typename BASE, int N>
struct multi {
  multi(typename nested<BASE,N>::initializer_list& init) {
  };
};
```

Unfortunately, neither of my versions of gcc have working initializer_list support, so I can't test this properly.